# Changing the name for 'categories' of x axis while implementing crossfilter with highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, crossfilter

I am trying to implement crossfilter along with highcharts. In the dataset, I have a key called 'date'. The values in the date key is of the form 'yyyy-mm' (for ex, 2018-04).

While implementing, I want the X axis to contain the dates in the format described here: for 2018-04, it should display June-18, and so on.

I was able to implement this by extracting the month and year from the date key. But, whenever the category names in the x axis is different from that given in the dataset, the crossfilter is not working correctly, i.e, whenever I click on any of the bars, every other chart's value is updated to zero. But when I set the x axis's categories back to the form given in the dataset, it works fine.

Comment: Could you reproduce your current attempt with sample data on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: I don’t know highcharts, but in D3 this would be solved by changing the formatting of the ticks rather than the source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implememnt this through xAxis.labels.formatter